# Fill whole div with an image regardless of image size not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fill a whole div with an image, regardless of the size of the image, but for some reason the image is only as big as it's default size. It does not automatically stretch to fit the size of the div. I tried setting the width and height of the image to 100%, thinking that it'll fit the div that way, but the image still stayed in its default size. Is there a way to automatically stretch an image to fill a div, without testing and changing each image by hand?

```
<style>

div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-image: url("side.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

</style>

<div> </div>
```

Comment: Your code works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/zLchdsf2/ (250x250px image filling the entire 1000x1000px div)

Comment: You can also do it by setting the image as the background image of the div and using `background-size:cover;` to fill the div: http://jsfiddle.net/zLchdsf2/2/

Comment: Are you expecting the background-image you've specified to be affected by the 100% width? Because that's not how it works - the img { width: 100%} rule will apply to an img *element* (as in @APAD1's JSFiddle) As he says, you can use `background-size`, though the correct value is `cover`, not `contain` (`contain` will preserve the aspect ratio of the image, meaning if your image is not square, it will not fill the 1000x1000 div)

Comment: @APAD1 I don't understand. It's not filling the whole div for me.

Comment: @APAD1 no worries - go ahead and post it as the answer; you got there first ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your question, it is unclear whether you are trying to use a background image or an [img](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) element to fill the div.

If you want to fill the div using an `img` element, the code you've posted will already do that for you. You just need to place an `img` element within the div, such as:

```
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" /></div>
```

If you want to stretch the image to fill the div using it as a background image, you simply need to add the value `cover` to the [background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) property:

```
background-size:cover;
```

[JSFiddle for img element](http://jsfiddle.net/zLchdsf2/)

[JSFiddle for background image](http://jsfiddle.net/zLchdsf2/2/)

Comment: Happy to help, glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

The `<img>` tag is an html element that has nothing to do with the background image of that `<div>`.

As APAD1 correctly points out, the proper way to force a background image to fill an html element is to use `background-size`.

- `background-size: contain` fills the element until the background image touches the first edge of its container (maintaining the aspect ratio).
- `background-size: cover` fills the element entirely while maintaining the aspect ratio of the image.
- `background-size: 100% 100%` fills the element entirely so that the background image touches the edge of the element on all sides (thus potentially distorting the image).